# Mount partition to several directories in Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

I have a PC with an SSD and an HDD. I'm running Linux. I wish to put all the static (very rarely changing) files on the SSD and the rest on the HDD. To achieve that I'd like to have /boot, /usr, /lib, /bin, /etc, /opt on the SSD and the rest - /var, /tmp, /home on the HDD. However, I don't want to create a separate partition for each of them, I want each group to be on its own partition. I suppose that I could mount the SSD to /, the HDD to /mnt/hdd and symlink /home, etc. to point to /mnt/hdd/home, etc.

Are there problems I can expect with such a setup? Such as a program attempting to read from/write to /var early in the boot process before the HDD is mounted? Will logging work as normal if /var (and /var/log) aren't on the root partition?

What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after more digging around, I found this is the correct incantation for a systemd-based setup:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system>        <dir>         <type>    <options>          <dump> <pass>
devpts                 /dev/pts      devpts    defaults            0      0
shm                    /dev/shm      tmpfs     nodev,nosuid        0      0

UUID=246b032f-0633-459a-867c-6013304c5b8d swap     swap defaults                             0 0
UUID=64ed9a87-7860-4538-bef6-05eff29ed5c1 /        ext4 defaults,noatime,nodiratime,iversion,fail 0 1
UUID=e3b656bf-69c8-4b2a-bad8-6c051559b43f /mnt/hdd ext4 defaults,noatime,nodiratime,iversion,x-initrd.mount,fail 0 1
/mnt/hdd/home                             /home    none rw,rbind,x-systemd.automount,fail 0 0
/mnt/hdd/root                             /root    none rw,rbind,x-systemd.automount,fail 0 0
/mnt/hdd/tmp                              /tmp     none rw,rbind,x-initrd.mount,fail 0 0
/mnt/hdd/var                              /var     none rw,rbind,x-initrd.mount,fail 0 0
UUID=B084-4D66                            /boot/efi vfat defaults,noauto,noatime,nodiratime,iversion 0 2
```

For whatever reason, tmp and var have to be x-initrd.mount, while home and root have to be x-systemd.automount. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mount --bind`, e.g. `mount --bind /mnt/hdd/home /home`

From [the `mount` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> After this call the same contents is accessible in two places. One can also remount a single file (on a single file).

(Note that this binding does not follow other mounts, so if you have a separate partition mounted on `/boot`, then doing `mount bind / /troll/root` will not include anything from the `/boot` partition.  If you want a recursive bind, use `--rbind`.)

[To do this in `fstab`](https://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab), put `none` in the FS column and `bind` in the options column, e.g.

```
/mnt/hdd/home       /home       none       bind
```

According to [the `fstab` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab), "The order of records in **fstab** is important because **[fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)**(8), **[mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)**(8), and **[umount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/umount)**(8) sequentially iterate through **fstab** doing their thing", so entries like this should appear after (below) the entry mounting a physical device on `/mnt/hdd/home`.

I'm not aware of any problems with this approach, but I have not tried the setup you describe.  I have used a separate partition for `/var/log` without problem, and I wouldn't expect a bind mount to have any additional effect.  If you're not booting from `/`, I would use a separate partition just for `/boot`, because it must be handled a certain way by the bootloader.

Comment: Thank you. Is the order of entries in /etc/fstab deterministic (i.e. from top to bottom, I'd expect) and is it still deterministic under systemd?

Comment: Updated to address the order of fstab entries.